# How to prove monotonicity of the following functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, regression-analysis

Consider, $t:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
t(\lambda) = \text{argmin}_x\{f(x)+\lambda g(x)\}, \quad \quad\lambda \geq 0
$$ 
which is assumed to be welldefined, where $f$ and $g$ are positive  and strictly convex and convex respectively (not that I think it matters for my question).

My intuition and also computer verifications, tells me that 
$f(t(\lambda))$ and $g(t(\lambda))$ are weakly increasing and weakly decreasing respectively.

***How should I proceed to actually show this?***

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "weakly increasing" and "weakly decreasing"?

Comment: Monotonically increasing. That is, increasing but not strictly increasing. Vice versa for weakly decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\lambda_1< \lambda_2$, set $t_i:=t(\lambda_i)$. Then by optimality
$$
f (t_1)  +\lambda_1 g(t_1) \le f (t_2)  +\lambda_1 g(t_2)
= f (t_2)  +\lambda_2 g(t_2) + (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) g(t_2)  \\
\le f(t_1) + \lambda_2 g(t_1) + (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) g(t_2).
$$
Hence $g$ is decreasing:
$$
(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) (g(t_2)-g(t_1))\ge0.
$$
If $\lambda_1=0$, we have also $f(t_1) \le f(t_2)$.

Assume now $\lambda_1>0$. Then we can repeat the above arguments
for minimization of $\lambda^{-1} f + g$. And we find the inequality
$$
(\lambda_1^{-1} - \lambda_2^{-1})(f(t_2)-f(t_1))\ge0,
$$
which means that $t\mapsto f(\lambda(t))$ is increasing.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much @daw.